# Split vector by a first appearance of another vector

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have the following data:

```
   players trial choice
1        1     1      0
2        1     2      1
3        1     3      0
4        1     4      0
5        1     5      0
6        2     1      0
7        2     2      0
8        2     3      1
9        2     4      0
10       2     5      1
```

Now I want to create another vector ("split the data") based on the *first* appearance of "1" in choice
for each player:

```
     players trial choice new_vec
1        1     1      0       1
2        1     2      1       1
3        1     3      0       0
4        1     4      0       0
5        1     5      0       0
6        2     1      0       1
7        2     2      0       1
8        2     3      1       1
9        2     4      0       0
10       2     5      1       0
```

So for each player, before the first "1" choice, the new vector gets "1", and "0" after that.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` to get first occurrence of 1 in `choice` and assign row numbers below that as 1 for each `player`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(players) %>%
  mutate(new_vec = +(row_number() <= match(1, choice)))
  #We can also use `which.max
  #mutate(new_vec = +(row_number() <= which.max(choice)))

#  players trial choice new_vec
#     <int> <int>  <int>   <int>
# 1       1     1      0       1
# 2       1     2      1       1
# 3       1     3      0       0
# 4       1     4      0       0
# 5       1     5      0       0
# 6       2     1      0       1
# 7       2     2      0       1
# 8       2     3      1       1
# 9       2     4      0       0
#10       2     5      1       0
```

The same logic can be implemented in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, new_vec := +(seq_len(.N) <= match(1, choice)), players]
```

and base R :

```
df$new_vec <- with(df, ave(choice, players, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) <= match(1, x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ave`.

```
dat <- transform(dat, new_vec=ave(choice, players, FUN=function(x) 
  if (x[1] == 1) 1 else +!c(F, (cumsum(x) > 0)[-length(x)])))
dat
#    players trial choice new_vec
# 1        1     1      0       1
# 2        1     2      1       1
# 3        1     3      0       0
# 4        1     4      0       0
# 5        1     5      0       0
# 6        2     1      0       1
# 7        2     2      0       1
# 8        2     3      1       1
# 9        2     4      0       0
# 10       2     5      1       0
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- tructure(list(players = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), trial = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), choice = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `ave()` solution:

```
df$new_vec <-
  ave(x = df$choice, df$players, FUN = function(x) cummax(c(0, head(x, -1))) == 0)
```

In `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
df[, new_vec := as.integer(cummax(shift(choice, fill = 0)) == 0), by = players]
```

Reproducible data

```
df <- data.frame(
  players = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
  trial = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
  choice = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)
)
```